# Is math truly infinite or is it just theory?

Tags: mathematics, singularities

I imagine you can theoretically add +1 to any number But untill it happens it isnt so.

That + no free will = math is limited and has a definite value.

I imagine its tied in with conservation laws...
Whatever is possible to exist is pre-defined from the begging and nothing new is possible.

Can you imagine a way that conservation laws can be broken?

Comment: People invented maths and its rules, so whatever obeys those rules is real in maths. The real mystery is why maths applies so well to the universe.

Comment: @hdhondt Math is logic, are you implying that the universe is illogical?

Comment: "_That + no free will = math is limited and has a definite value._" what does that supposed to mean?

Comment: Oh I guess you are saying that "maths" is based on common sense, and it is impossible to produce results using maths without thinking something very radical - like how Einstein said that the speed of light has to be a constant, and absolute time does not exist?

Comment: @eromod Logic is human invention, just like math. Why should the universe follow nice simple rules, so humans can understand how it works?

Comment: { 42Mtpy6_Uow }

Comment: @KV18 That={I imagine you can theoretically add +1 to any number But untill it happens it isnt so}. no free will = {humans are entirely made of atoms that follow rules like; every action has an equal and opposite reaction}. math is limited and has a definite value = {the cycle of the universe is static and non changing}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to define not very coherently a [Hilbert program:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_program)

> In mathematics, Hilbert's program, formulated by German mathematician David Hilbert in the early part of the 20th century, was a proposed solution to the foundational crisis of mathematics, when early attempts to clarify the foundations of mathematics were found to suffer from paradoxes and inconsistencies. As a solution, Hilbert proposed to ground all existing theories to a finite, complete set of axioms, and provide a proof that these axioms were consistent. Hilbert proposed that the consistency of more complicated systems, such as real analysis, could be proven in terms of simpler systems. Ultimately, the consistency of all of mathematics could be reduced to basic arithmetic.

But there exist proofs that the system is open. [Have a look :](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems)

> Gödel's incompleteness theorems are two theorems of mathematical logic that demonstrate the inherent limitations of every formal axiomatic system capable of modelling basic arithmetic. These results, published by Kurt Gödel in 1931, are important both in mathematical logic and in the philosophy of mathematics. The theorems are widely, but not universally, interpreted as showing that Hilbert's program to find a complete and consistent set of axioms for all mathematics is impossible.
>
> The first incompleteness theorem states that no consistent system of axioms whose theorems can be listed by an effective procedure (i.e., an algorithm) is capable of proving all truths about the arithmetic of the natural numbers. For any such consistent formal system, there will always be statements about the natural numbers that are true, but that are unprovable within the system. The second incompleteness theorem, an extension of the first, shows that the system cannot demonstrate its own consistency.
>
> Employing a diagonal argument, Gödel's incompleteness theorems were the first of several closely related theorems on the limitations of formal systems. They were followed by Tarski's undefinability theorem on the formal undefinability of truth, Church's proof that Hilbert's Entscheidungsproblem is unsolvable, and Turing's theorem that there is no algorithm to solve the halting problem.

You say:

> Whatever is possible to exist is pre-defined from the begging and nothing new is possible.

With open systems there will always be something new. I had learned
Gödel's theorem in a course of set theory, back in 1960  as "the set of all sets is open".